# Menu is not styled properly and footer as well

Tags: css, theme-customizer

[image]

Here I want to remove bullets that is before the menu.

Here is my wordpress code for that menu :

```
<ul class="templatemo_menu">
    <li>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) ); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is my CSS:

```
.templatemo_menu {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 195px;
}
.templatemo_menu li a{
    background: #F4F4F4 url(images/button_default.gif) no-repeat;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0066CC;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
 * html .templatemo_menu li a{ 
      width: 190px;
  }
  .templatemo_menu li a:visited, .templatemo_menu li a:active{
      color: #0066CC;
  }
  .templatemo_menu li a:hover{
      background: #EEEEEE url(images/button_active.gif) no-repeat;
      color: #FF3333;
  }
```

index.php:

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="templatemo_left_column">
    <div class="text_area" align="justify">
        <div class="title">
            Free CSS Website Layout
        </div>

        This   free CSS  template is provided by <a href="#" target="_parent">xyz.com</a>. Feel free to download, modify and use this layout for your websites. It would be helpful if you put a kind of credit link back to <a href="http://www.xyz.com" target="_parent">xyz.com</a> website. Thank you.<br />

        <br />

        Proin vel libero id erat venenatis accumsan. Nunc blandit orci sit amet risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor nulla, congue vitae, fringilla in, varius a, orci. Mauris convallis. <br />

        <br />
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) { ?>
            <div class="section_box2" align="justify">
                <div class="post_title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text_area">
                    <?php the_post(); the_content();?>
                        <div class="publish_date">Post Date: <?php the_time('F jS, Y');?> By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?><?php _e( ' Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>· Tags: <a href="#">CSS</a> · <a href="#">Web Design</a> · <a href="#">Full Story</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }  } // end if ?>

        <div class="section_box2" align="justify">
            <div class="post_title">
                New Flash Player
            </div>
            <div class="text_area">
                <img src="images/s_flashmo_022_park_20.jpg" alt="Photo Two" title="Photo Two" width="120" height="90" class="templatemo_pic" />
                Nam sit amet justo vel libero tincidunt dignissim. Fusce ac orci sit amet velit ultrices condimentum. Integer imperdiet  odio ac eros. Ut id massa. Nullam nunc. Vivamus sagittis varius lorem.
                Quisque in diam a justo condimentum molestie.<br />
                <div class="publish_date">Post Date: 24-10-2020 · Tags: <a href="#">Flash</a> · <a href="#">ActionScripts</a> · <a href="#">Full Story</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar();get_footer();   ?>
```

Header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="templatemo_container_wrapper">
    <div class="templatemo_spacer"></div>
    <div id="templatemo_container">
         <div id="templatemo_top"> <a href="#" target="_parent">Website Templates</a> · <a href="#" target="_parent">Flash Templates</a> · <a href="#">Company</a> · <a href="#">Contact</a></div>
    <div id="templatemo_header">
        <div id="inner_header">
           <div id="templatemo_site_title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></div>
           <div id="templatemo_site_slogan"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

sidebar.php:

```
<div id="templatemo_right_column">
    <ul class="templatemo_menu">
        <li>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) ); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="section_box" align="justify">
        <div class="subtitle">
            Quick Contact
        </div>
            Tel: 002-040-0240<br />
            Fax: 001-050-0480<br />
            Email: info[at]templatemo.com<br />
            <br />
    </div>
    <div class="section_box" align="justify">
        <div class="subtitle">
            About this website
        </div>
        Curabitur velit tellus, placerat et, dapibus varius,  aliquet quis, purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  adipiscing elit.<br />
        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img  src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" width="88" height="31" vspace="8" border="0" /></a> 
    </div>
    <div class="section_box">
        <div class="subtitle">
        Special Thanks
        </div>
        <a href="#">Website Link One</a><br />
        <a href="#">Blog Link Two</a><br />
        <a href="#">Template Link Three</a><br />
        <a href="#">Text Link Four</a><br />
        <a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Free Templates</a><br />
</div>
<div class="section_box"><?php dynamic_sidebar('Right Hand Sidebar'); ?></div>
```

Here is my footer.php code:

```
<div id="templatemo_footer">
    Copyright © 2048 Your Company Name · <a href="#" target="_parent">Website Templates</a> by <a href="#" target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?> 
</div>
<div class="templatemo_spacer"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this also.

```
.templatemo_menu li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

This will remove bullets.

Comment: Great ! You helped 3rd time .. Thank you so much !

Comment: Great! Have fun!

Comment: theres one more problem in that related to footer .. I m finding difficulty in it but It might be very easy for you .. can you please me ?

Comment: Sure. Let me know.

Comment: Question Edited ..

Comment: That's issue with floats. You can try this. `#templatemo_footer{clear:both}`. If this does not work, post your website. Can't really help with this without looking at website.

Comment: included header.php, index.php footer.php and sidebar.php ...Do I need to add anything else ?

Comment: Read my above comment. I will need to firbug the code and css.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=82333619ACD02B1C!106&authkey=!AALAFUWQNhiPak0&ithint=folder%2cphp

Full content of my side excluding Images ..

Comment: No, I don't need code of this theme. I need to check website live to firebug it.

Comment: Its not live .. Its for my learning .. What should I do ?? :(
Without fixing this , I can not move ahead ..

Comment: There is not much I can do. Last suggestion, try adding `<br clear="all" />` before `<div id="templatemo_footer">`.